# load web images to MS Access forms

Tags: ms-access-2010

How can I show an image from the Internet on a MS Access form? For example, I'd like to show this image on my form: http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to ensure that the image you show in the access form gets updated if the image in the URL gets updated ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a webbrowser control would suit your purposes? Check out http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/video-add-web-browsing-to-a-form-VA101814124.aspx and http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-web-browsing-to-a-form-HA101631434.aspx for more info. They do more than display images, but might get the job done for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it was a pain getting a picture to fit the web browser control. so I gave up and started using the attachment field.